# The following packages have unmet dependencies: libpulse-dev

Tags: 14.04, package-management, pulseaudio, dependencies, compiling

Ok so i'm trying to build from source and to do that I must install it's dependencies.

So one of the dependencies is the following:

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~/dev/RBDOOM-3-BFG/neo(master)$ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I check `libpulse-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1+kxstudio1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (= 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1+kxstudio1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

From here I'm pretty much stuck. I'm aware that pulse is responsible for the sound, but I'm lost as to how to fix such an issue.

I also tried everything this answer had to offer: https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/130518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the suffix was the culprit, the `+kxstudio1` to be specific.

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~/dev/RBDOOM-3-BFG/neo(master)$ apt-cache policy libpulse0
libpulse0:
  Installed: 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1+kxstudio1
  Candidate: 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1+kxstudio1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1+kxstudio1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:4.0-0ubuntu11 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Install the one listed under trusty:

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0=1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1
```

Do the same with `libpulse-mainloop-glib0`.

Now it works to install the other packages! :D

I'm using `KXStudio`, when installing it must have changed the packages with custom packages.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as the right one!
I had the same issue with kxstudio repos when installing pulseaudio, and another time with installing some version of wine. I wonder if it is something that could be fixed by the kxstudio maintainer, with a differently formatted suffix?

Comment: @stragu I'll see when I have time and file a bug report on github.

Comment: actually, it might have been a repo misconfiguration that has already been fixed, please see this post by the maintainer, FalkTX: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=17434&p=84171#p84136